# ZFS shows pool state FAULTED, but all devices are ONLINE; how can I recover my data?

Tags: freebsd, zfs, data-recovery, truenas, zpool

Our 100TB NAS based on FreeNAS 8 was unexpectedly powered off due to power failure. After turning it on back, 100TB zpool "projects" was unmounted with state "FAULTED".

I've tried `zpool import -fFX`, it was running for about 20 hours, but nothing happened. I've rebooted server with reset button because kill -9 and reboot comands did not work.

Some outputs:

```
[root@Projects_new] ~# zpool import
   pool: projects
     id: 8560768094429092391
  state: FAULTED
 status: The pool metadata is corrupted.
 action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
    The pool may be active on another system, but can be imported using
    the '-f' flag.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-72
 config:

    projects                                      FAULTED  corrupted data
      gptid/49d49544-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE    ok
      gptid/49f3c886-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE    ok
      gptid/4a1052aa-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE    ok
      gptid/4a32bf15-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE    ok
      gptid/4a9b51d3-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE    ok
      gptid/4b2ee18b-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE    ok
```

Also I've found undocumented option: `zpool import -V projects`, after that zpool was imported, but still unaccesible:

```
[root@Projects_new] ~/zpool_restore# zpool status
  pool: projects
 state: FAULTED
status: The pool metadata is corrupted and the pool cannot be opened.
action: Destroy and re-create the pool from
    a backup source.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-72
  scan: none requested
config:

    NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    projects                                      FAULTED      0     0     1
      gptid/49d49544-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     0
      gptid/49f3c886-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     2
      gptid/4a1052aa-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     2
      gptid/4a32bf15-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     2
      gptid/4a9b51d3-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     0
      gptid/4b2ee18b-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

In this state, `zpool clear -f projects` outputs "I/O error".

/dev/gptid/4* are RAID0 devices: 4 on 4 Adaptec controllers and 2 on 1 LSI controller.

Is there any way to import and fix zpool and save data?

Comment: I think it's pretty clear you need to restore from a backup. Why is it all RAID0 anyway? I'd bet if you had some redundancy, this may have been recoverable. I've regularly (though on 4.5TB array, so much smaller) pulled power on a RAIDz2 array and had NO problems. (Note this is at home though, as a media server, not work related)

Comment: `zpool import -fF` is your best bet. Let it run, until it returns something. But if you have a working backup: Just restore, thats probably faster.

Comment: Now I'm checking drives on 3 RAID controlles with checksum errors. `zpool import -fF[X]` did not output anything for about 30 hours so I decided to check the drives and run command again.

Comment: Does the system in question have fully ECC RAM everywhere (both host RAM and controller caches)? It *should*, since you are posting here, but I have heard of more than one horror story not entirely unlike this that eventually got traced back to non-ECC RAM...

Answer (score 2):

```
NAME                                          STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
projects                                      FAULTED      0     0     1
  gptid/49d49544-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     0
  gptid/49f3c886-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     2
  gptid/4a1052aa-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     2
  gptid/4a32bf15-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     2
  gptid/4a9b51d3-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     0
  gptid/4b2ee18b-5a47-11e2-b516-00259095142c  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

> /dev/gptid/4* are RAID0 devices: 4 on 4 Adaptec controllers and 2 on 1 LSI controller.

So let me just start out by getting something straight. You have a ZFS pool which consists of six devices (as seen by ZFS), striped with no redundancy. Each one of these consists of some unknown number of physical storage devices, themselves striped with no redundancy. A conservative estimate says you have somewhere on the order of 20-25 spinners, quite possibly more, *all of which have to work perfectly* for your setup to be stable. Remember that physical disk failures are *at best* uncorrelated, and in practice tend to happen in batches in shared environments (if one disk fails, it's likely that one or more others are marginal and may even fail simply under the stress of resilvering). This makes the best case scenario such that with 25 disks, the probability of failure is 25x that of a single disk, because you have 25 of them each with the same probability of failure as it would have had were it alone.

Now some of those drives (or possibly controllers) apparently have developed some sort of problem, which has trickled through and is being reported by ZFS.

At that point, my question is more or less "what do you expect ZFS to do?". And unfortunately, I think the answer both to that as well as your question is that **no, there really isn't a whole lot to be done at this point.**

**ZFS isn't magic.** It is highly resilient to many different types of failures, but once it breaks, it has a tendency to do so in spectacular ways. You can reduce the risk of breakage by using its redundancy features, which for whatever reason you have opted to not do. Its complex on-disk format also makes recovery a lot more complicated than e.g. UFS, NTFS or ext3/4.

If `zpool import -fFX` doesn't get your pool back to a usable state, then your best bet might very well be to just recreate the pool in a sane manner and restore the most recent backup. This includes adding some redundancy, such that even if a whole controller or power supply fails the entire pool doesn't fail. Also, configure your controllers to expose the raw disks in a JBOD fashion to ZFS, and use ZFS' redundancy support to add redundancy to your storage; that allows ZFS to make decisions about where to place data and how to arrange redundancy to try to reduce the risk of failure. (For example, metadata can be stored redundantly by copying it to multiple independent vdevs.)

Comment: Such a high incidence of ZFS troubles with FreeNAS users here.

Comment: @ewwhite I haven't checked, but might it be related to people taking a server-grade workload and pinning it on consumer-grade hardware and knowledge? (Not understanding storage redundancy, thinking you'll be fine with non-ECC RAM, etc.) Not saying it is so in this particular case, obviously. Compare [ECC vs non-ECC RAM and ZFS on the FreeNAS forum](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/ecc-vs-non-ecc-ram-and-zfs.15449/).

Comment: I've found a solution. The only way to run 'zpool import' was to manually write some TXGs to devices with dd.

Comment: @SergeyAndrianov That does not appear to seek clarification or suggest improvements to *this* answer. If you came up with a solution, please add it as an *answer* to your question, giving all relevant details.